# Python Error: Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to python, so please, bear with me!

This function:

```
def kerf(X,m):
        [n_samples, ]= X.shape
        n_sa, n_fe = m.shape
        ker = np.zeros((n_samples, n_sa))
        for i, x_i in enumerate(X):
            for j, m_j in enumerate(m):
                ker[i, j] = (np.dot(x_i, m_j))  # problem is here!!
        return ker
```

I call it like this:

```
Z=kerf(myarray[0,[0,1]],myarray[:,[0,1]])


ker[i, j] = (np.dot(x_i, m_j))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

myarray is basically the same matrix. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replace the problem line with:

```
print(np.dot(x_i, m_j).shape)
```

it repeatedly prints `(2,)`.

`ker[i, j]` takes 1 value; 2 values is `sequence`.

Please give us the dimensions of the arrays at various points, such as `myarray` (I guessed and tried a (3,4)), and at the problem point.  `print(...shape)` is an essential debugging tool in `numpy`.

Do you need help on figure out why it's `(2,)`?  May I suggest stepping through the loop in an interactive shell, looking at shapes at various points along the way.

---

the 2 inputs to the `dot` look like:

```
(1.0, array([ 1.,  1.]))
```

a scalar, and a 2 element array - so the `dot` is also a 2 element array.

You need to explain what size you expect these 2 arrays to be, and what size you expect the `dot`.  Actually we can get the result - it's got to be `(1,)` or a scalar - 1 value to put in the one slot `ker`.

---

You can probably replace the double iteration with a single `dot` product (or if need be with an `einsum` call).  But let's get this iteration working first.

Comment: myarray[0,[0,1]] contains just one row of these two numbers [1,233 0.6675] while myarray[:,[0,1]] contains like 12 rows of pair values like [1.879 0.5656]. I just wanna the dot product of the one row array with all the elements of the 12 rows array.

Comment: With this one liner: ker = np.dot(myarray[0,[0,1]],np.transpose(myarray[:,[0,1]])) I can make it work, however i am not sure if it's quite good.

Comment: Or shorter `myarray[0, [0,1]).dot(myarray[:, [0,1].T)`,  That looks like a good `dot` usage.  Transpose if often used with matrix multipication to correctly pair dimensions.